# Magento - Add bundled products from PHP with Magento API

Tags: php, api, soap, magento

Is it possible to add bundled products with Magento API? If not, is there any other way to add a bundled product?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is way around, which I myself have been playing with for some time. Please see this post ([Programmatically add Bundle Products in Magento, using the SKU / ID of Simple Items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108775/)) to get a starting point of how to proceed.

I have used simple way to add Bundle Products, not by using Web Services. However, I think the latter is still possible.

Comment: Yes, I solved this in a similar way. I logged the post data when creating a bundled product in the admin and then I used this to replicate this step.

I have not tried to use this through the Web Services yet, but it should work as it does internally.