# Programatically added bundle product isn't showing up in frontend

Tags: php, magento, bundle

I am trying to insert bundled products to the Magento database from a PHP script. The version in question is Community 1.5.1.0.

I tried the method described in the question "[Programmatically add Bundle Products in Magento, using the SKU / ID of Simple Items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108775/programmatically-add-bundle-products-in-magento-using-the-sku-id-of-simple-ite)". The inserted products show up nicely in the administration section -- I can edit them, add new options and selections etc. However, they are not showing up at all in the Magento frontend no matter what I try - e.g. rebuilding indexes or re-saving them from the back-end. Adding bundles through the administration interface works fine.

After some digging through the database, I noticed there are no necessary entries in the `catalog_product_index_price` and `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_idx` tables when using my script, while adding the bundle through the back-end updates the indexes normally. Re-indexing simply ignores the added bundle product as far as those tables are concerned.

I dug through the Magento source files and can't find any hints on what I'm doing wrong. All caches are disabled, selections are in stock, and I tried to include all data I dug up while studying the POST request Magento sends while inserting the product in the back-end.

Here's the complete script I use for testing, along with some desperate attempts commented out at the bottom:

```
$magentoPath = '/home/nikola/bin/magento-1.5/';
require_once($magentoPath . 'includes/config.php');
require_once($magentoPath . 'app/Mage.php');

$storeID = 1;
$websiteIDs = array(1);

$mageObj = Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($storeID);

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

$cats = array("210");
$p = array(
  'sku_type' => 0, 
  'sku' => 687, 
  'name' => "BarProduct", 
  'description' => 'Foo', 
  'short_description' => 'Bar',
  'type_id' => 'bundle', 
  'attribute_set_id' => 4, 
  'weight_type' => 0, 
  'visibility' => 4, 
  'price_type' => 0, 
  'price_view' => 0, 
  'status' => 1, 
  'created_at' => strtotime('now'), 
  'category_ids' => $cats, 
  'store_id' => $storeID, 
  'website_ids' => $websiteIDs
);

$product->setData($p);

$product->setCanSaveBundleSelections(true);
$product->setCanSaveCustomOptions(true);

Mage::register('product', $product);
Mage::register('current_product', $product);

$optionRawData = array();
$selectionRawData = array();

$optionRawData[0] = array(
  'required' => 1,
  'option_id' => '', 
  'position' => 0,
  'type' => 'select',
  'title' => 'FooOption',
  'default_title' => 'FooOption', 
  'delete' => ''
);
$selectionRawData[0] = array(); 
$selectionRawData[0][] = array(
  'product_id' => 1810,
  'position' => 0,
  'is_default' => true,
  'selection_id' => '', 
  'option_id' => '', 
  'selection_price_type' => 0,
  'selection_price_value' => 0.0,
  'selection_qty' => 1,
  'selection_can_change_qty' => 1,
  'delete' => ''
);

$product->setBundleOptionsData($optionRawData);
$product->setBundleSelectionsData($selectionRawData);

$product->save();

/*
$stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item');
$stockItem->loadByProduct($product->getId());
if (!$stockItem->getId()) {
  $stockItem->setProductId($product->getId())->setStockId(1);
}
$stockItem->setData('is_in_stock', 1);
$stockItem->save();

$pi = Mage::getSingleton('bundle/price_index');
$pi->addPriceIndexToProduct($product);
$pi->save();
*/

?>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Please try using the following code & see what happens:-

```
<?php
$magentoPath = '/home/nikola/bin/magento-1.5/';
require_once($magentoPath . 'includes/config.php');
require_once($magentoPath . 'app/Mage.php');

$storeID = 1;
$websiteIDs = array(1);
$cats = array("210");

Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

$p = array(
  'sku_type' => 0,
  'sku' => '687',
  'name' => "BarProduct",
  'description' => 'Foo',
  'short_description' => 'Bar',
  'type_id' => 'bundle',
  'attribute_set_id' => 4,
  'weight_type' => 0,
  'visibility' => 4,
  'price_type' => 0,
  'price_view' => 0,
  'status' => 1,
  'created_at' => strtotime('now'),
  'category_ids' => $cats,
  'store_id' => $storeID,
  'website_ids' => $websiteIDs
);

$product->setData($p);
Mage::register('product', $product);
Mage::register('current_product', $product);

/**
 * Section of Bundle Options
 * 
 * Required Properties of Bundle Options are:-
 * 1. title
 * 2. option_id
 * 3. delete
 * 4. type
 * 5. required
 * 6. position
 * 7. default_title
 */
$optionRawData = array();
$optionRawData[0] = array(
  'required' => 1,
  'option_id' => '',
  'position' => 0,
  'type' => 'select',
  'title' => 'FooOption',
  'default_title' => 'FooOption',
  'delete' => '',
);

/**
 * Section of Bundle Selections
 * 
 * Required Properties of Bundle Selections
 * 1.   selection_id
 * 2.   option_id
 * 3.   product_id
 * 4.   delete
 * 5.   selection_price_value
 * 6.   selection_price_type
 * 7.   selection_qty
 * 8.   selection_can_change_qty
 * 9.   position
 * 10.  is_default
 */
$selectionRawData = array();
$selectionRawData[0] = array();
$selectionRawData[0][] = array(
  'product_id' => 1810,
  'selection_qty' => 1,
  'selection_can_change_qty' => 1,
  'position' => 0,
  'is_default' => 1,
  'selection_id' => '',
  'selection_price_type' => 0,
  'selection_price_value' => 0.0,
  'option_id' => '',
  'delete' => ''
);

$product->setCanSaveConfigurableAttributes(false);
$product->setCanSaveCustomOptions(true);

// Set the Bundle Options & Selection Data
$product->setBundleOptionsData($optionRawData);
$product->setBundleSelectionsData($selectionRawData);
$product->setCanSaveBundleSelections(true);
$product->setAffectBundleProductSelections(true);

$product->save();
?>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It works! Thank you very, very much. I just compared your version to mine, and it seems the problem was in the `Mage::register('current_product', $product);` part -- commenting it out did the job. Once again - thanks and cheers!

Comment: Yes, the registration of the variable "`current_product`" seems inappropriate since no product have been saved till the very last line of code. Also I've added another line, which is also very important, "`$product->setAffectBundleProductSelections(true);`". And Cheers for the working!

Comment: @KnowledgeCraving can you help me with this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12698975/magento-bundle-product-is-not-displayed-right-on-front-end-after-programmaticall .
Thanks :)_

Comment: @Knowledge Craving I added your code as such, product is added in admin section, and if I open product and resave from admin panel(without making any changes) then it starts showing up in front-end. Please help me if know any solution. I am using magento 1.7.02

Answer (score 4):

I have tried using your code, but it did not seem to work in Magento 1.7.0.2. Apparently the product could not be saved.

What I did was added the following lines:

```
 Mage::register('product', $product);
 Mage::register('current_product', $product);
 $product->setCanSaveConfigurableAttributes(false);
 $product->setCanSaveCustomOptions(true);
```

Just before the lines:

```
// Set the Bundle Options & Selection Data
$product->setBundleOptionsData($optionRawData);
$product->setBundleSelectionsData($selectionRawData);
$product->setCanSaveBundleSelections(true);
$product->setAffectBundleProductSelections(true);

$product->save();
```

This seemed to fix the issue of not being able to save the file.

Comment: Thanks for providing that info! I'm updating my answer as well.