# Magento - Programatically added bundle product isn't available for the basket/frontend

Tags: php, magento, indexing, bundle, product

I followed this answer which works fine: [Magento - Programatically added bundle product isn't showing up in frontend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161128/magento-programatically-added-bundle-product-isnt-showing-up-in-frontend/6161246)

I'm able to generate a bundle product on the fly. Everything works fine.

Only one problem: My bundle product is correctly saved and I can see it through the admin area. But, after this generation on the fly, I have to add directly this product into the basket. The system returns "product not found". Basically, I have to go into the admin area, just save it and then I'm able to add it to the basket.

I really suspect a problem with the indexer but I can't really figure out what's going on.

I tried many solutions like:

```
Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->processEntityAction(
     $product, 
     Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, 
     Mage_Index_Model_Event::TYPE_SAVE
);
```

But it still doesn't work.
Any Idea about which code I should trigger after the save method to index **only** this new added bundle product.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: After generating your product, was any index marked as invalid on administration?

Comment: Sounds to me like you're not saving the product into a Store/Website view. Resaving the product through the admin will update this attribute. Can we see the code you use to create the product?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are not creating a stock-item with your product. Therefore there is no stock and you can't add it to your basket?

Have a look into

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php:672
/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php:571
```

where a product is generated and the stock data are cleand up / set with default data