# How 2 o more products can be selected and created as one product in magento?

Tags: php, jquery, magento

I am working in magento and creating functionality something like on this page http://www.kokoblack.com/shop/chocolate-picker.html, my question is how i can select 2 or more products and with that selected products, i want to create one box or one product id and send to the cart. is that possible?

Or how the above link's functionality can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

This would be a bundle product. http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/creating-a-bundled-product

Comment: And that's a pretty neat set up they have there. I don't know if that page is something they created themselves, or if it's a purchased extension. Magento's bundle products by default are either drop-down select boxes, radio, or checkboxes.

Comment: can i group these products dynamically means with coding or without using admin panel?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108775/programmatically-add-bundle-products-in-magento-using-the-sku-id-of-simple-it  This might help. I've never tried it. Once I got the bundle products figured out in the admin, I just started importing all of my products through a CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

This is called a '[Grouped](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/modules_reference/english/mage_adminhtml/catalog_product/producttype#grouped)' or '[Bundled](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/modules_reference/english/mage_adminhtml/catalog_product/producttype#bundle)' product. click [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-grouped-product) to see how to create a grouped product, or click [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/creating-a-bundled-product) to learn how to create a bundled product.

Comment: Thanks for the answer..can Bundled product can be created dynamically or with coding?

Comment: yes see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108775/programmatically-add-bundle-products-in-magento-using-the-sku-id-of-simple-it