# Magento bundle products - selection_id cannot be null?

Tags: sql, magento, bundle

I am trying to create a bundled product programmatically, and setting the options via this:

```
            $new_options[$count] = array(
                'required' => 0,
                'position' => 1,
                'parent_id' => $parentProduct->getId(),
                'type' => 'select',
                'title' => $product->getName(),
                'default_title' => $product->getName()
            );
            $new_selections[$count] = array(array(
                'product_id' => $product->getEntityId(),
                'selection_qty' => $child['qty'],
                'selection_can_change_qty' => 0,
                'position' => 0,
                'is_default' => 1,
                'selection_price_type' => 0,
                'selection_price_value' => 0.0
            ));
      ...
    $parentProduct->setBundleOptionsData($new_options);
    $parentProduct->setBundleSelectionsData($new_selections);
```

Which looks correct (as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/4415800/494643). However, it is not working - I get an SQL exception complaining that `Column 'selection_id' cannot be null'`. How do I get around this? The selection id is an auto_increment column, so I can't get it until it is created, but it looks like it cannot be created?

Comment: could you give us the whole function to be able to try it locally? also, what Magento version are you trying to make that work on?

Comment: Version: 1.12.0.2 (enterprise). Whole function is not needed - this is enough to reproduce, just use Mage::getModel to load two products and try it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution lies in the _beforeSave function of the `Mage_Bundle_Model_Selection` model.

This causes it to attempt to write the selection_id to the `catalog_product_bundle_selection_price` table, **before** it has saved the selection object - and therefore before it has generated a selection_id. The answer therefore is to force it to generate an id before it saves, so looking again at the _beforeSave function, we can see that it only saves the price if the store is not 0.

Specifically, this part:

```
$storeId = Mage::registry('product')->getStoreId();
if (!Mage::helper('catalog')->isPriceGlobal() && $storeId) {
```

which means that if we set the store id of the registry product to 0 first, we can cause it to save the selection, without saving the price. We would then need to reset the store to the previous value, and save again, to record the price - although only after having reloaded the object to get the newly generated selection id.